# Tensorflow: When should I use or not use `feed_dict`?

Tags: tensorflow

I am kind of confused why are we using `feed_dict`? According to my friend, you commonly use `feed_dict` when you use `placeholder`, and this is probably something bad for production.

I have seen code like this, in which `feed_dict` is not involved:

```
for j in range(n_batches):
    X_batch, Y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    _, loss_batch = sess.run([optimizer, loss], {X: X_batch, Y:Y_batch})
```

I have also seen code like this, in which `feed_dict` is involved:

```
for i in range(100): 
    for x, y in data:
        # Session execute optimizer and fetch values of loss
        _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={X: x, Y:y}) 
        total_loss += l
```

I understand `feed_dict` is that you are feeding in data and try `X` as the key as if in the dictionary. But here I don't see any difference. So, what exactly is the difference and why do we need `feed_dict`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In a tensorflow model you can define a placeholder such as `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)`, then you will use `x` in your model.

For example, I define a simple set of operations as:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = x * 42
```

Now when I ask tensorflow to compute `y`, it's clear that `y` depends on `x`.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(y)
```

This will produce an error because I did not give it a value for `x`. In this case, because `x` is a placeholder, if it gets used in a computation you must pass it in via `feed_dict`. If you don't it's an error.

Let's fix that:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: 2})
```

The result this time will be `84`. Great. Now let's look at a trivial case where `feed_dict` is not needed:

```
x = tf.constant(2)
y = x * 42
```

Now there are no placeholders (`x` is a constant) and so nothing needs to be fed to the model. This works now:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(y)
```

Comment: (First of all, I am new to it). On your last example, using a constant, if you use a variable instead, what would be the difference between variable and placeholder, as I can also change the variable value? Thanks

Comment: This is more geared towards TF 1.x. If you're new to this you'll be using 2.x and should follow guides for TF 2.x which changes the way things are computed substantially.